# Javascript - build plugin for requireJS

Tags: javascript, requirejs, amd

I have writted a Javascript plugin and I want to make it compatible with requireJS. However, I have some difficulties to make it work properly. I think my AMD is not correctly writted or something like this.

When I try to execute the plugin constructor it's not defined after requireJS have loaded the script ( the callback variable from requirejs is not defined also).

For example I use requirejs like this:

```
requirejs([
'./assets/js/myplugin.js'
], function( myplugin) {

    console.log(myplugin); // undefined
    new MyPlugin(); // undefined

});
```

And in myplugin.js I have this script:

```
(function (root, factory) { 

if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {

    define(
        'myplugin',
        ['brandname-util1/util1',
        'brandname-util2/util2',
        'brandname-util3/util3'],
        factory
    );

} else if (typeof exports === 'object' && module.exports) {

    module.exports = factory(
        root,
        require('brandname-util1'),
        require('brandname-util2'),
        require('brandname-util3')
    );

} else {

    root.MyPlugin = factory(
        root,
        root.BrandNameUtil1,
        root.BrandNameUtil2,
        root.BrandNameUtil3
    );

}

}(this, function factory(root, util1, util2, util3) {

    'use strict';

    var MyPlugin = function() {
    }

    return MyPlugin;

}));
```

The script is correctly loaded (Asynchronously) but nothing is defined. I'm not sure to fully understand how it works.

**EDIT**: here the utils scripts example:

```
// util1
(function(root, factory) {

    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {

        define(
            'brandname-util1/util1',
            ['jquery'],
            factory
        );

    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {

        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));

    } else {

        root.BrandNameUtil1 = factory(root);

    }

}(this, function() {

    "use strict";

    var util1 = {};

    // declare some functions

    return util1;

}));

// util2
(function(root, factory) {

    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {

        define(
            'brandname-util2/util2',
            ['jquery'],
            factory
        );

    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {

        module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));

    } else {

        root.BrandNameUtil2 = factory(root);

    }

}(typeof window !== "undefined" ? window : this, function() {

    "use strict";

    var util2 = function() {},
        proto = util2.prototype;

    // declare some proto

    return util2;

}));

// util3
(function (root, factory) { 

    if (typeof define === 'function' && define.amd) {

        define(
            'brandname-util3/util3',
            ['brandname-util1/util1',
            'brandname-util2/util2'],
            factory
        );

    } else if (typeof module === 'object' && module.exports) {

        module.exports = factory(
            root,
            require('brandname-util1'),
            require('brandname-util2')
        );

    } else {

        root.BrandNameUtil3 = factory(
            root,
            root.BrandNameUtil1,
            root.BrandNameUtil2
        );

    }

}(this, function (root, util1, util2) {

    "use strict";

    var util3 = function() {},
        proto = util3.prototype;

    // declare some proto

    return util3;

}));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only problem I see is that your factory takes `root` as the first argument and then the modules. It works fine in the CommonJS (2nd branch) and no module system (3rd branch), but it fails in the AMD case (1st branch) because `define` will call your factory with only 3 arguments: `root` will be set to the first module of the dependency list, `util3` won't be set, etc.

If you do not in fact use `root` in your factory, you could just remove it from the parameter list and adjust the calls in the 2nd and 3rd branch to not pass it, and everything should work.

Otherwise, if you do need it in your factory, you could fix it by changing your first branch to do:

```
define(['brandname-util1/util1',
    'brandname-util2/util2',
    'brandname-util3/util3'],
    factory.bind(undefined, root)
);
```

This sets the value of `this` in the factory to be `undefined` (which should be fine) and forces the first parameter in the factory to be set to the value `root` has in the scope of your `define` call. The modules are then appended after it.

See this documentation on [bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind) for more details of how it works.

You should also not set a module name in your `define` call. The call I show above removes the module name. The call should only have the dependency list and the factory.

And you should not put `.js` in module names. So `requirejs(['./assets/js/myplugin'],` without the `.js`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It doesn't solve the issue and everything is still undefined.

Comment: I've edited my answer with two other issues that I did not notice earlier.

Comment: Thank you. I can't make it work. I think I'm confused in the way to correctly  handle old my util dependancy. I have edited my question by adding all the code of the utils.

Comment: I don't have much time now but glancing at your code, I see the same issue with `root`, and calling `define` with a hardcoded module name as the 1st parameter recur in your other modules. You need to go over all your modules and make the same correction as for the code you originally had in your question.

Comment: If I remove the hardcoded module name the dependency fails and the script is breaked. It seems that I must define a name in order to use it in another anonymous AMD module.

Comment: Ok. I think I finally succeed to make it work thanks to your advices. I removed the root everywhere and also removed the module name only for the main AMD module because the others are already loaded in the same file (for the moment). I think I need to harcode the name only if the module is already in the same file. But not sure about that.